# How to force a specific wsdl endpoint via web.config, behind a reverse proxy with address translation

Tags: vb.net, iis, web-config, reverse-proxy

we have an Nginx reverse proxy set to send traffic from:

```
https://ws.mydomain.com/staging/service.asmx
```

to our IIS Server 10:

```
http://localmachine/ws/staging/service.asmx
```

(sending ***ws.mydomain.com*** as host header)

The problem is that when we call `https://ws.mydomain.com/staging/service.asmx?WSDL` the auto-generated wsdl shows a **MIXED** endpoint:

```
<soap:address location="http://ws.mydomain.com/ws/staging/service.asmx"/>
```

instead of

```
<soap:address location="https://ws.mydomain.com/staging/service.asmx"/>
```

I googled a lot but I couldn't find a way to force, via web.config, a specific URL - or to specify a base address (everything BEFORE service.asmx).

Answer (score 1):

In the `Apache` server, the functionality could be achieved by the `ProxyPreserveHost` directive when the Apache works as a reverse proxy.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost
There is no `ProxyPreserveHost` in `Nginx`, but you can try `proxy_set_header` directive.

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

Please refer to the below links.
https://serverfault.com/questions/87056/when-nginx-is-configured-as-reverse-proxy-can-it-rewrite-the-host-header-to-the
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache/
Also, here is a workaround for overriding the WSDL location property.
[WebService behind reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213911/webservice-behind-reverse-proxy)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Hi, we have set already proxy_set_header, but it just solves the "domain" part, it doesn't affect the translated address. Please note that our nginx is translating /staging/service.asmx to /ws/staging/service.asmx , so the heades is not enough